# Show decimal comma instead of decimal point

Tags: php, decimalformat, decimal-point

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to set the decimal "point" to a decimal comma, instead of a decimal point?

[Field on Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBEEQ.png)

> DB Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
>   Table: Type: decimal(15,2)| Function: (empty field) | Value: 0.00

I have already played around with this function in php:

```
if (!function_exists('DisplayMoney')) {
    function DisplayMoney($amount, $hide_currency = 0, $hide_zeros = 0)
    {
        $newamount = number_format($amount, 2,'.', '');
    }
}
```

This ends with an error, and my site isn't accessible anymore.

[jquery.min.js](https://pastebin.com/SbP60Fd4)
[html5shiv.js](https://pastebin.com/6d95XXZb)
[cb.js](https://pastebin.com/RhX8rTYZ)

Comment: Please review [how to ask](StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other links in the help section, then `edit` to include the *exact* error message, minimum code needed to reproduce the issue, and to ensure that your question is self-contained, meaning that links are *supplementary*, but *not required* in order to have all the info necessary for volunteers to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

use

`$number = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $string_number)));`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions, I would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set the decimal comma instead of decimal point you must only set the third parameter fo the `number_format` function to `,` and leave the fourth parameter as blank.

```
 $newamount = number_format($amount, 2,',', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this don't solve the problem. " Please enter correct amount"

Comment: Is please enter correct amount your error?

Comment: according to my answer you can echo and check the result it is correct.

Comment: old  $newamount = number_format($amount, 2,'.', '');
new $newamount = number_format($amount, 2,',', '');
for both parameters the message show up "Please enter correct amount" when I enter amount with decimal comma (e.g. 1,90)

Comment: have you set any pattern to your input?

Comment: no I just brought this script... Sorry I'm newbie :(
I guess I need to hire a freelancer to help me.

Comment: No need to worry just provide me your html and js(if any) code

Comment: I have a 
functions php with $newamount = number_format($amount, 2,'.', '');
withdrawl php inside paramters like this $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, getPostParameter('amount'));
and
$amount = DisplayMoney(MIN_PAYOUT_PER_TRANSACTION, $hide_currency = 1);
 if (isset($_POST['amount']) && is_numeric($_POST['amount']))
 {
  $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, getPostParameter('amount'));
 }

Also the entry from sql in my first post.

Comment: Ok just try to remove `&& is_numeric($_POST['amount'])`.

Comment: Same error "Please enter correct amount"

Comment: This is not a php error this is a javascript validation error so i'll need your js code for it.

Comment: Edit your question and add your js code in it.

Comment: I have 11 js files but I think it must be in one of the files I add